# Is this user a sockpuppet?

Tags: discussion

I wonder how the (bleep) did this answer get "accepted", and looked at the question. The account [redacted] was created and only this one post was ever made.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot provide an answer in accordance with moderation policy, and leaving the question open to other answers only invites baseless speculation.

Comment: @Qmechanic I find these redactions a bit too verbose, particularly on the title. Maybe "Is this user a sockpuppet?" would do equally well?

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right. I just want to drive home the fact that this question has essentially been asked N times before in various incarnations, cf. the right margin. And the answer is always the same: The moderators are not allowed to disclose non-public information about other users.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yeah, but still, it's a mouthful, it looks attention-grabby and faintly click-baity, and I'm not sure our meta front page is the place for repeated Harry Potter references. There's two points to be made, (i) that calling out users by name, particularly in titles, is not OK, and (ii) that moderation questions are not discussed publicly, and using a solution to (i) to try to hammer in (ii) is grabbing the stick by the wrong end to me. "Is this user a sockpuppet?" works perfectly fine, or you can use "Is [redacted] a sockpuppet?" to really hammer it home.

Comment: As always, editing is a collective effort. If you think you can improve, you are welcome to do so.

Comment: @Qmechanic For sure. I just didn't want to start an edit war; it's also more relevant for future cases than any one specific instance. :-).

Comment: How do you decide what to redact? I was reading about a user who posted jokes and strange questions, and the OP stated the number in a silly way, and at least one comment linked to it normally.  But here you even erased the initials (not actual name) from the title.

Comment: @JDługosz: Which comment?

Comment: It was somewhere in [this thread](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4764/policy-regarding-intentionally-counter-productive-users), @Qmechanic.

Comment: Thanks. I have now removed the username in that thread.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We (moderators) don't discuss details of moderation actions, so we're not going to answer the question of whether a particular account is a sockpuppet.

For future reference, the appropriate way to report something like this, which concerns a specific account, is via a flag, not a meta post.